# Multiple choice question about the set $A = \{ m + n\sqrt{2} \}$.

Tags: real-analysis

let $A = \{m + n \sqrt{2}\}$ where $m,n$ are integers, then

$a.$ $A$ is dense in $R$.

$b$. $A$ has no limit point in $R$.

$c$. $A$ has only countably many limit points in $R$.

$d$. only irrational numbers can be limit point of $A$

Set $A$ is similar to the set $N \times N$, so all points are isolated in $A$.
therefore option $b$ should be correct.
In answer key, option $a$ is marked as correct.
Please suggest if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You say "Set $A$ can be represented as $(m,n\sqrt2),\ldots$".

Comment: I edited the question!

Comment: You now say "Set $A$ is similar to the set $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$". Similar? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\alpha=\sqrt2-1$. Then $\alpha^n\in A$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ (why?)
and $\alpha^n\to0$. So $0$ is a limit point of $A$, which contradicts (d).

In general, if $I$ is an open interval in $\Bbb R$ then $\alpha^n$
is less than the length of $I$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and then $m\alpha^n\in I$
for some $m\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.  Can't this set be similar to $Q \times Q$ or $N \times N$ in terms of cardinality?